# VBScript passing value by reference (VarPtr) to ActiveX function

Tags: vbscript, pass-by-reference, activex, wsh

I'm trying this:

```
  Dim oApp
  Dim iReturnedResult

  Set oApp = CreateObject("Some.Application")
  Set F_Ord = oApp.Documents.Open("Window 1", VarPtr(iReturnedResult))
```

The ActiveX control expects the second parameter to be a Long by reference.

This works perfectly well inside Excel VBA.
I can run this step by step, and see the result is returned like it should.

But, when I move this code to a VBS file and run it from the command line (CScript.exe), I get an error **800A000D**, meaning it's the wrong type.

I have also tried creating an array instead, and tested with these commands, without any luck:

```
Set F_Ord = oApp.Documents.Open("Window 1", VarPtr(iReturnedResult(0)))
Set F_Ord = oApp.Documents.Open("Window 1", iReturnedResult(0))
```

Does anyone know how to pass a long variable by reference to an ActiveX control from VBScript?

Comment: `VarPtr()` is not supported in VBScript.

Comment: You could try `Dim iReturnResult: iReturnResult = CLng(0)` then pass that as the argument, but not sure it will work if a pointer is expected.

Comment: Ah, you're right, VarPtr is supported by VBA but not VBScript. Thanks.

And thanks for the suggestion on CLng, didint work though.

Comment: Didn't expect to if I'm honest, as it's expecting a pointer which `CLng()` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is `VarPtr()` is not supported by VBScript.

To my knowledge, there is no equivalent that allows you to pass a pointer to a variables memory address.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Visual Basic for Applications Features Not In VBScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/30593abb(v=vs.84))